# Why font Awesome does not work when sending marketo E-mails

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome, marketo

I am using Marketo to send e-mails. Within these e-mails I am using font awesome to create the social media icons. However it is not appearing in the e-mail when it is sent.

To import the font I am using the following:

```
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Most email clients do not support external stylesheets.

Comment: i have done all the style inline, and added the <link> within the head

Comment: how did you add the link? Using a cdn or to somewhere in your server?

Comment: Either way, I doubt if any email program would find a CDN.

Comment: Email clients are not the best HTML renderers. Stick to very basic layout and formatting if you want things to work. Webfonts are not basic.

Comment: i used cdn for font awesone

Comment: i also used google font 'Lato; i used both <link> and @import, yet it wasn't picking up font Lato either

Comment: Have you opened a support ticket with Marketo? This sounds like a product support question.

Comment: yeah i have - thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to avoid using external stylesheets, as most email clients will block them. That said, you are on the right track. Here's how to do this:

1. Load the external stylesheet.

   ```
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   ```
2. Reference the font-family in your CSS.

   ```
   h1 { font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight: 400; }
   ```